# Adding a filter using security descriptor in FwpmFilterAdd function of WFP

Tags: security, wfp

I want to prevent anyone from deleting my registered filter except my account.
I wonder that is possible if I set security descriptor in FwpmFilterAdd function.
And could you show me source code of example which adds a filter using security descriptor for my purpose?

I read "Hindering Filter Deletion" and "Forcing Filter Deletion" in WFP msdn.
Is there any method preventing anyone from forcing filter deletion?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, just for context, these are the links to sample code you were referring to:

- [Hindering Filter Deletion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb427375(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Forcing Filter Deletion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb427372(v=vs.85).aspx)

The samples there simply illustrate how to use [FwpmFilterSetSecurityInfoByKey0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364064(v=vs.85).aspx) and [FwpmFilterGetSecurityInfoByKey0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364061(v=vs.85).aspx) API. However the practical purpose of the specific scenario chosen for these samples is quite dubious. Why would anyone want set explicit ACLs on WFP filter to disable DELETE access to the world, along with disabling WRITE_DAC and WRITE_OWNER? For all practical purposes, **local administrators** can always take ownership of the object back, then overwrite the security descriptor (which is what the "Forcing Filter Deletion" sample is doing). **Non-administrators** cannot take ownership of other account's objects, and cannot delete WPF filters even with default security descriptor, that will be given to the filter by passing NULL as third parameter to FwpmFilterAdd.

To answer your question, no you don't need to secure it any further. You will not gain any more security by using the "Hindering Filter Deletion" technique. The best that technique is doing is adding small layer of obfuscation. Your default DACL you get for WFP filter is BFE engine DACL, described [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb442405(v=vs.85).aspx) With default DACL only local administrators have DELETE access. And local administrators can do anything to the system by definition, so there is no point of security anything from administrators.